# What is the tail truncation mark on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, tail, truncation

I want to add some tail marks to several strings. Are there any marks like '\n' on iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean Objective-C ? Well, it's just like C, the character '\n' represents a newline.